# Why I cannot override getString() in Activity

Tags: android, inheritance, android-context

`getString(...)` is declared `final` in `Context` class in Android. Why it has to be `final`?

I will be checking translations stored in `HashMap` downloaded from our server so overriding `getString(...)` in our app `BaseActivity` seems obvious to me.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not standard Android development. If you want to do that, you can write your own method and use it, you don't need to override `getString()`.

Comment: How it is not standard? Can you please elaborate?  Whats the downside of this approach?

Comment: Getting the translations from a remote server is not supported by Android SDK right now. The Android resource API supports local translations only. If you want to use your own resource API it is fine, but you don't have to override `getString()`, you can just write another method.

Comment: I have written `getTranslation(...)` but `getString(..)` is more suitable I think, because other developers in my team don't have to know about `getTranslation(..)`

Comment: Still overriding `getString()` is not an option. The simplest option is to let the others know there's a new API that supports remote strings.

Comment: I understand that. My question is why `getString(...)` has to be `final`?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java), I have good news for you: `getString()` actually only calls `getResources().getString()`, and you can override `getResources()`, so technically you can actually override `getString()` indirectly.

Comment: I will extend `Resource` then I will override `getString(...)` in `MyResource` then in activity I can override `getResources` to return instance of my extended class. Am I right?

Comment: You're right, sir. In fact now I remember I already did something similar to be able to load icons from external storage and it worked perfectly. However remember to fall back to some default strings in case there's no network ;)

Answer (score 1):

`getString()` is final because it is just calling `getResources().getString()` and `getResources()` is overridable, which means you can just extend `Resources` class and override its `getString()` method.